# UPDATE values from one table using values from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables mysql with the info:

TABLE A

| torneo | equipo | importe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 100.00 |
| 3 | 2 | 200.00 |

TABLE B

| equipo | torneo | importe | deuda | pago |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 20.00 | 20.00 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 300.00 | 300.00 | 1 |

And I need know how to update the value from `IMPORTE` on `TABLE B` only if `PAGO` column on `TABLE B` are value `0` with the content of `TABLE A` column `IMPORTE` where `equipo` and `torneo` from both tables are the same.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an update join here:

```sql
UPDATE TableB b
INNER JOIN TableA a
    ON a.torneo = b.torneo AND
       a.equipo = b.equipo
SET b.importe = a.importe
WHERE b.pago = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution.

```
UPDATE `TableB`AS b
INNER JOIN `TableA` AS a
ON  a.torneo = b.torneo AND
    a.equipo = b.equipo
SET b.importe = a.importe
WHERE b.pagos = 0;
```